# Driving transmission line with a MOSFET

Tags: mosfet

I want to drive a 48 pF/m, 150 ohm, 500 m to 3 km long transmission line with a MOSFET for my TDR (time domain reflectometer) project.
I am going to use this [logic level MOSFET](https://www.mouser.de/datasheet/2/916/PSMNR51-25YLH-1665953.pdf). The MOSFET is conducting when the gate-source voltage is between 1.2 and 2.2 V.

I want to use the circuit below. The resistance is 150 ohm.

[image]

The voltage source will be replaced by a µController. I will feed a 3.3 V 5 ns pulse into the MOSFET, so it should drive the line also with a 3.3 V 5 ns pulse. And I should see a reflection of 1.65 V at some point.

The simulation shows that everything works as expected.

In my previous project I used a opamp to drive this transmission line and it worked fine. The problem with a opamp is that its bandwidth is not the best.

But I am concerned that the MOSFET can't source enough current since drain is connected to the µController. So the maximum current that the MOSFET can source will be dependent on the maximum current the µController can source, right?

EDIT:
I think this circuit is better. The current will not be limited by the µController. But the source is now floating

[image]

EDIT2:I think this circuit should work. The current will not be limited by the µController. The source is not floating anymore. The source is connected through a 10MOhm resistor to ground

[image]

Comment: Don't use that circuit. Where did you get the idea that connecting the drain to a uC was a good idea? Use either a resistor or another FET to the drain.

Comment: @Neil_UK a resistor from the µController to drain? But still the current that will be sourced is quite low

Comment: That simulation diagram does not look right, it shows the voltage pulse being connected to the drain which means that the mosfet isn't really doing anything at all. The pulse should be connected to the gate.

Comment: @VoltageSpike I will try it, but the problem is if I only connect the µC to the Gate, I need another voltage source for drain. This will introduce a DC offset

Comment: In real life you will need a voltage source connected to the mosfet, a better way would be to find an active driver with the specs you want at the impedance you want. Also if you remove the fet from the above sim, you'll get the same result.

Comment: @VoltageSpike what are your thoughts on my 2nd circuit?

Comment: @Yoomo Much better, realize also that in real life all wires have resistance and inductance, and all voltage sources have source resistance, so that will need to go into the model (right now all of your wires and sources in the sim are superconducting, and we don't have room temp superconductors so you couldn't build the above circuit)

Comment: @VoltageSpike Yes I know that. The current from drain to source will be now dependet on the voltage source connected to drain. But the problem now is that the source is floating. Do you think this will be a problem in real life application? I need a gate source voltage of around 1.5V

Comment: @VoltageSpike would it help if I connected a high value resistor from source to gnd, so it isn't floating?

Comment: `EDIT: I think this circuit is better. The current will not be limited by the µController. But the source is now floating` Your second circuit is slightly less wrong. The source is floating. Connect a resistor or current source to the source to pull current from it, so that you can get both source and sink current into the transmission line.

Comment: @Neil_UK do you mean a resistor from source to drain? Could you upload a image of your circuit

Comment: @Neil_UK a resistor from source to drain will introduce a offset. Is there another way?

Comment: @Neil_UK I connected the source through a 1MOhm resistor to ground, gate shouldn't be floating anymore, right?

Comment: @Yoomo Finally. Now let's get some current through that resistor. Let's make it a  1 k instead of 1 M, and connect it to -10 V instead of ground.